# getting errors while using annotations in spring

Tags: java, spring

i am getting errors when using `@Requestmapping` in `LoginController.java`.

Getting errors like

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type 
     RequestMapping
    - RequestMethod cannot be resolved to a variable
    - The attribute method is undefined for the annotation type 
     RequestMapping
    - RequestMapping cannot be resolved to a type and some other errors also.
Please check bean.xml file also.
```

LoginController.java

```
package control;
import model.User;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
@Controller
public class LoginControl{
private ApplicationContext context = null;
private UserJDBCTemplate userJDBCTemplate = null;
public LoginControl(){
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
    userJDBCTemplate = (UserJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("userJDBCTemplate");
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView userLogin() {
    return new ModelAndView("login", "command", new User());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/loginCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String checkUser(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")User user, ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());                    
      if(userJDBCTemplate.checkLogin(user)){
          return "loginsuccess";
      }          
      return "loginerror";
}   
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView userAdd() {
    return new ModelAndView("add", "command", new User());
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")User user, ModelMap model) {
      model.addAttribute("username", user.getUsername());                    
      if(userJDBCTemplate.create(user)){
          return "addsuccess";
      }         
      return "adderror";
}
}
```

beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:annotation-config/> 
<context:component-scan base-package="control"/>
<bean id="dataSource"                                                                                       
   class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login"/>
  <property name="username" value="root"/>
  <property name="password" value="infoobjects"/>
</bean>

<!-- Definition for userJDBCTemplate bean -->
<bean id="userJDBCTemplate"   class="control.UserJDBCTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />   
</bean>      
</beans>
```

Comment: you should implement [`ApplicationContextAware`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html?is-external=true) to get a bean from `container`.

Comment: ApplicationContextAware is one option and putting the applicationContext files in context-param which will make them available everytime as we have listeners.

Comment: actually i am new to spring so can you give me an example how to implement ApplicationContextAware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your classpath for `spring-webmvc.jar` file is available or not,
Assuming you using a eclipse, then to conform a class is available or not in `classpath`. click **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>**, A OpenType window will open, in the typename type RequestMapping. if it show's in Matching items then it's available else not. In your case it's not that's why you getting error

```
The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type
```

Secondly, To get a bean from container there are many ways like

1. By implementing [BeanFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.5/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) interface
2. By implementing [ApplicationContextAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) interface

for example to get bean by using `ApplicationContextAware` interface it provides a `setApplicationContext()` to get access context.

```
public class LoginController implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
  private UserJDBCTemplate userJDBCTemplate;

  public String checkUser(){

     //get your UserJDBCTemplate bean from container and use it
     userJDBCTemplate = (UserJDBCTemplate)context.getBean("userJDBCTemplate");
  }

  //Here, spring will set ApplicationContext
  void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
  }
}
```

But these are bad ways, cause are not Inversion of Control(IoC). you should use spring's iversion control.

In your bean configuration file, you have declared `<context:annotation-config/>`, But you not using this tag functionality, which is used for activating various annotations in bean classes like `@Required`, `@Autowired`, `@PostConstruct`, `@PreDestroy` and `@Resource` (if available).

So in your case you should use `@Autowired` annotaion to inject `UserJDBCTemplate` bean

to use IoC you have to modify your beans configuration file like @freakman said in his answer.

add `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`

**Note:**
To use above tag, add this schema to top of your beans configuration file.

```
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
```

change your `LoginController` class constructor to use constructor injection like:

```
@Autowired
public LoginControl(UserJDBCTemplate userJDBCTemplate){
    this.userJDBCTemplate = userJDBCTemplate;
}
```

Here Spring will automatically provide you `UserJDBCTemplate` bean to use.

Comment: @user3345514 what error u getting post it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add spring-web dependency to your `pom.xml/classpath`.

You will also have to add `< mvc:annotation-driven/>` to your `beans.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

add spring-web jars on build path if you are not using pom.xml. Download all the jars 
[http://www.javatpoint.com/src/sp/springjars.zip](http://www.javatpoint.com/src/sp/springjars.zip.)

And if you are using pom.xml then add spring-web dependency.